# Bibliography not appearing (Natbib, Mendeley)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm new to LaTeX and am trying to switch from hardcoded `\bibitem` references to `natbib`. I have all my references in Mendeley and exported them to a `.bib` file. My code is generating no errors (yay!) but is also failing to make any references appear. All of the documentation I've read suggests that one only needs `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` to make them appear...any thoughts? I looked at the `.bib` file and it appears to match everything expected (I also tried to construct a MWE with only one reference but it still failed to appear). All I get is my "test" text.

Thanks for any insights!

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ulem, setspace, fullpage}
\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 

\begin{document}
test
\newpage
\bibliography{Zotero-Coresidence}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: You didn't mention whether you ran BibTeX as well as LaTeX. Please advise. Please also report if there are error messages in the `\jobname.blg` file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this comment. I ran pdfLaTeX and then BibTeX and then pdfLaTeX again, but there are no .blg files in the folder--just .aux, .run, and .bbl (in addition to the Tex file).

Comment: Are you saying that there's a new `\jobname.bbl` (where `\jobname` is the name of your main tex file) in the folder, but no file named `\jobname.blg`?

Comment: There are no citations in your example, so it's not surprising you see no bibliography. If you want to add a bibliography without citations, use `\nocite` (selectively) or `\nocite{*}` (add everything).

Comment: I tried adding in \nocite{*} (I have cites in the real paper; this was just a trivial example) and it hasn't changed anything. @Mico, Here are the files with the same base name as my main file:

.aux
.txt
.pdf
.synctex.gz
.bbl
(no extension shown, filetype is Performance Monitor)

Comment: Thanks for providing a list of the files in your working directory that have the same basename as the tex file. It's rather odd that there would be a file with extension `bbl` (short for "bibliography", created by the bibtex run) but no associated `blg` (short for "bibtex log") file. The latter is created during a bibtex run; the fact that it's not around might suggest that something really odd is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from you bibliography path. Also you should be aware that it us easier to place your bibliography in the same directory and then just write the name ' biblio' (without the .bib extension). You can also make relative references. Say your bibliography is in another subfolder in your project. Then you can write 'bib/biblio'

Comment: That true. I will update my answer.

Comment: I removed the quotes and put it in the same folder so that I can reference it directly. I ran BibTeX after pdfLaTeX and then ran pdfLaTeX again. Now I'm getting a page that actually says "References" on it, but doesn't have any references displayed.

Comment: Run pdflatex twice, then bibtex and then pdflatex

Comment: Or maybe it is to times after bibtex.. Usually most modern latex editor's will use latexmk script that figures the whole thing out.